# Are Questions about Downloads on-topic?

Tags: discussion, closing

I was about to flag the following question:

[Having trouble downloading the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221777/having-trouble-downloading-the-game)

The question is regarding Yandere-Simulator, which is a game that is in development, but is free to play, and can be downloaded at the developer's page, as a testing build.

However, none of the flags actually applies to it, as it's gaming related, however, it's not ... actually regarding gaming.

Comment: It is, however, asking about a game. I suppose, in the most technical sense, it's not a gaming issue, but it is about supporting a game.

Comment: I have to **slightly** disagree here (I suppose depending on the situation). If the question were to be strictly about downloading some file, I don't think that has much to do with gaming in the on-topic sense and it would be a more Super User-y than anything. However, if the game was downloaded and there was an issue running or setting up the game itself, that is definitely on topic as supporting the game. I just don't see downloading a file as game support (unless it were through a service like Steam or whatever that had the issue).

Comment: I'm referring to scenarios as in the example provided, the user has no game installed, and wishes to download the game or updates themselves. The downloads aren't via a client such as steam or uplay